# VetoSet NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, list

I've been working on a program that parses and interprets some data, but I've been running into a problem. No matter how hard I try, I can't seem to stomp out this bug.

Code snippet: http://pastebin.com/0BLakSpe 
VetoSet.java: http://pastebin.com/8RdGKGQw 
Result: http://pastebin.com/8GfxndGw

I've modified the code so you don't have to trudge through lots of unrelated methods, and I've modified the error message so it makes sense in the context of the code I've posted.

Here's the full code for those who want to read it: 
Main.java: http://pastebin.com/FenKU6Ze 
VetoSet.java: http://pastebin.com/8RdGKGQw 
VetoParser.java*: http://pastebin.com/1vTF3aXP 
ReadFile.java: http://pastebin.com/beV0bqPa 
Interpolate.java: http://pastebin.com/3CsaJdXm 
Utility.java: http://pastebin.com/4G8ZmYxp

Here's a tarball of compilable code: http://www.qfpost.com/file/d?g=KFaF7M6dk

If anyone could help me with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
taktoa

* The rotatePairArrays function has some debugging code added on

Comment: You haven't shown us enough.  The error occurs because `n` is null in `doStuff`.  The code that's causing the trouble must be whatever is calling `setVetoPairs` to establish what `getVetoPairs` will return, but I can't see the "set" calls anywhere.  Maybe you're never calling it?  In that case the result is unsurprising.

Comment: I posted Main.java below, and I can tell you that my data files and VetoSets contain valid data. It seems like my VetoSet array might have more entries than VetoSets though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `VetoStuff.vetoSetToPairArray()`:

```
    Pair[][] pairArray = new Pair[input[0].getVetoPairs().length][input.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
            pairArray[i] = input[i].getVetoPairs();
```

You have switched the two dimensions in the 2d-array. Since `input[0].getVetoPairs().length > input.length` your pairArray will end up with some nulls at the end.

Change it to:

```
new Pair[input.length][];
```

(you are overwriting the inner arrays anyway when you assign them two lines later).

Comment: All of the CSV files I'm reading in have valid data, so I think it's more a problem of it looping past the filled portion of an array. Unfortunately, I can't find anything that would cause that in my code.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention that "interpBetweenVetoSets" is the "doStuff" method in question.

Comment: @taktoa: I was mistaken. The problem was in VetoStuff.vetoSetToPairArray()

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't shown us enough. The error occurs because `n` is null in `doStuff`. The code that's causing the trouble must be whatever is calling `setVetoPairs` to establish what getVetoPairs will return, but the "set" calls must be inside the parser.  It's leaving one of the values null.

This should be very easy to find by tracing in the debugger. Netbeans is brilliant for this sort of thing.

In the past I have been caught by not handling blank lines correctly. It could be something simple like that.  The debugger will probably make it clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to a big IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans on this computer, so I have to use basic println debugging.

Comment: Then you should either build a unit test for the parser or add a "debug" option to the parser class that prints the value of each array element as it's created. It has to be that at least one of the array elements it's producing is null. EIther of these techniques will show the problem. I'm sorry I'm not going to be able to dig into all this code.